# Not able to show particular column data in angular material table

Tags: json, angular

***I have been trying to show my JSON data in material table but one of my column 'user name' is not showing any data in table.can anybody share code of how i can show userName data  in table.I am new to angular so i don't know how i can traverse through JSON.***

Here is my json from api.

```
[
       {
          "studentId": 1,
          "clientId": 1,
          "regNo": "s101",
          "firstName": "shrey",
          "middleName": "prakash",
          "lastName": "soni",
          "gender": "m",
          "birthDate": "2000-12-05",
          "aboutMe": "Tech enthusia",
          "profileSummary": "android developer",
          "user": {
             "userId": 1,
             "userType": 1,
             "userName": "shreysoni",
             "activeState": 0
          }
       },
       {
          "studentId": 2,
          "clientId": 1,
          "regNo": "s102",
          "firstName": "jay",
          "middleName": "prakash",
          "lastName": "soni",
          "gender": "m",
          "birthDate": "2000-12-01",
          "aboutMe": "Cook",
          "profileSummary": "Web dev",
          "user": null
       },
       {
          "studentId": 3,
          "clientId": 1,
          "regNo": "s103",
          "firstName": "harsh",
          "middleName": "prakash",
          "lastName": "gurnani",
          "gender": "m",
          "birthDate": "2000-01-18",
          "aboutMe": "Architect",
          "profileSummary": "Construction",
          "user": {
             "userId": 2,
             "userType": 1,
             "userName": "harshgurnani",
             "activeState": 1
          }
       },
       {
          "studentId": 6,
          "clientId": 1,
          "regNo": "s104",
          "firstName": "Dennison",
          "middleName": "Hulke",
          "lastName": "Malyon",
          "gender": "M",
          "birthDate": "2019-12-22",
          "aboutMe": "Nam nulla. Integer pede justo, lacinia eget",
          "profileSummary": "Nam nulla",
          "user": null
       }
    ]
```

Here is displaycolumn array list :

displayedColumns: string[] = ['select', 'registerNumber', 'firstName', 'middleName', 'lastName', 'userName', 'isActive'];

Here is user name column def

```
<!-- UserName Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="userName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> User Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" data-title="User Name:"> {{element.userName} </td>
      </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the `user` node of your json

and if `user` is null, you can handle it with null propagation as below

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="userName">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> User Name </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" data-title="User Name:"> {{element.user?.userName}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Can u tell me what is null propogration i mean '?' this means

Comment: it means if user is null, the expression does not execute anything after the `?`
element.user?.userName become an UI empty string (instead of raising exceptions)
and if user has a defined value, then the userName is used

Comment: I also want to ask u i have toggle button i want if username exits then i want to show it on UI otherwise i dont want how i can implement it

Comment: you can use an `*ngIf="element.user?.userName"` in the button tag, it should work
 (don't forget to mark the answer as answered I love my green ticks)

Comment: <ng-container matColumnDef="isActive">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Is Activated </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" *ngIf="element.user?.userName"  data-title="User Name:" ><mat-slide-toggle></mat-slide-toggle></td>
      </ng-container> this is my code

Comment: place the ngif in the `mat-slide-toggle` tag instead, (we cannot have a ngif an a `td` tag with `matCellDef` ortherwise it errors

Comment: Thanks man . U  helped me so much .last can u recommend me  some angular tutorials as i am mobile dev guy.

Comment: np, I always advise people to do the "tour of heroes" tutorial from angular.io

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="userName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> User Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" data-title="User Name:"> {{element.user.userName}} </td>
      </ng-container>
```

Comment: after pasting your code , in user name column getting '{{element.user.username}}' as output

Comment: i can see u have not put } at end .now data is coming but new issue is i am having a null in some users so app throws error